# how to add Set<String> value to the List in the for loop?

Tags: java

I would like to iterate the Value of the `accountset` `List<AccountTO>` and set to `AccountID`.

Actually in the `accountset` I am getting the values : `100,101,102` I would like to add the values to the `List<AccounTO>` and set them to `AccountID` and pass it to the Service call. Is there any that I can go with or else any other procedure.

```
for(String s :group.getAccounts().keySet())
{
    System.out.println("===="+s.lastIndexOf("-"));
    System.out.println("sub"+s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("-")));
    accountSet.add(s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("-")));
}
```

Comment: really poor question structure, solution is probably simple if you would put effort in writing your question a bit better

Comment: @prashanth please reformat your question and explain it better, I can't understand what is the input and what code should do

Comment: Set<String> accountSet = new HashSet<String>(); i need to add the accountset to the list<AssetAllocationTO>

Comment: What kind of object is `AssetAllocationTO`

Comment: It consists of private String AccountID

Comment: @prashanth reddy was that the solution to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly it should be fairly simple :

```
List<AssetAllocationTO> someList = new ArrayList<AssetAllocationTO>();

for (String string : group.getAccounts().keySet()){
            AssetAllocationTO al = new AssetAllocationTO();
            al.setAccountID(string);
            someList.add(al);
}
```

Comment: The Values are in accountset ,there is no need of it?